# Ignore error and continue in C#

Tags: c#, error-handling, try-catch

I'm trying to open 3 programs in C#, however, I would still like the code to continue if an error occurs.  In other words, programs 2 and 3 should still try to open if something fails on program 1.  I also don't want to check for File Existance as the program takes some switches and anything can fail.
The code below will bomb out if program 1 fails.  How can I ignore any errors and still continue the code?

```
try
{
        string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup);
        //Program 1
        Process x = Process.Start("\"C:\\Program Files\\Company\\Office\\MyProgram1.EXE\"   /runtime  \"C:\\Program Files\\Company\\Config.xml\" /cmd RunServer");
        //Program 2
        Process x = Process.Start("\"C:\\Program Files\\Company\\Office\\MyProgram2.EXE\"   /runtime  \"C:\\Program Files\\Company\\Config.xml\" /cmd RunServer");
        //Program 3
        Process x = Process.Start("\"C:\\Program Files\\Company\\Office\\MyProgram3.EXE\"   /runtime  \"C:\\Program Files\\Company\\Config.xml\" /cmd RunServer");
}
catch {}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use 3 different `try-catch` blocks

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup);
try {        
    //Program 1
    Process x = Process.Start(path + "/runtime  \"C:\\Program Files\\Company\\Config.xml\" /cmd RunServer");
}
catch {}
try {
    //Program 2
    Process x = Process.Start(path + " /runtime  \"C:\\Program Files\\Company\\Config.xml\" /cmd RunServer");
catch {}
try  {
    //Program 3
    Process x = Process.Start(path + " /runtime  \"C:\\Program Files\\Company\\Config.xml\" /cmd RunServer");
catch {}
```

Answer (score 9):

A separate `Try...Catch` for each process is probably the best way to do it. However if you could have any number of programs, you could use a `foreach` loop instead of manually writing the `Try...Catch` for each call.

```
List<Action> processesToCall = new List<Action>();  

string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup);
processesToCall.Add(() => Process.Start("\"C:\\Program Files\\Company\\Office\\MyProgram1.EXE\"   /runtime  \"C:\\Program Files\\Company\\Config.xml\" /cmd RunServer"));
processesToCall.Add(() => Process.Start("\"C:\\Program Files\\Company\\Office\\MyProgram2.EXE\"   /runtime  \"C:\\Program Files\\Company\\Config.xml\" /cmd RunServer") );
processesToCall.Add(() => Process.Start("\"C:\\Program Files\\Company\\Office\\MyProgram3.EXE\"   /runtime  \"C:\\Program Files\\Company\\Config.xml\" /cmd RunServer") );    

foreach(Action a in processesToCall)
{
    try
    {
       a();
    }
    catch
    {
       //log  (or whatever you want to do with it)
    }
}
```

This way you won't have to write a `Try...Catch` block for each action and so it's easier to add more actions.

Answer (score 0):

Seems strange that you want to ignore errors. Anyway, you can put each process start in a try catch block:

```
try{
   Process.Start(...);     
}catch(Exception e){
   //log error, if you want
}
```